# bind9 strange logs and lot of them

Tags: bind

This is my log from bind, these request don't stop comming and named uses a lot of cpu

```
    27-Sep-2018 21:34:19.693 queries: info: client 217.107.34.85#25183 (jk1l.ru): query: jk1l.ru IN ANY +E (192.168.0.200)
27-Sep-2018 21:34:19.738 queries: info: client 109.148.129.56#15451 (jk1l.ru): query: jk1l.ru IN ANY +E (192.168.0.200)
27-Sep-2018 21:34:19.796 queries: info: client 217.107.34.85#22807 (isc.org): query: isc.org IN ANY +E (192.168.0.200)
27-Sep-2018 21:34:19.805 queries: info: client 74.99.171.161#80 (jk1l.ru): query: jk1l.ru IN ANY +E (192.168.0.200)
27-Sep-2018 21:34:20.242 queries: info: client 142.112.165.146#80 (eftps.gov): query: eftps.gov IN ANY +E (192.168.0.200)
27-Sep-2018 21:34:20.243 queries: info: client 122.114.207.223#80 (aids.gov): query: aids.gov IN ANY +E (192.168.0.200)
27-Sep-2018 21:34:20.302 queries: info: client 217.107.34.85#36681 (isc.org): query: isc.org IN ANY +E (192.168.0.200)
27-Sep-2018 21:34:20.368 queries: info: client 92.11.206.190#80 (aids.gov): query: aids.gov IN ANY +E (192.168.0.200)
27-Sep-2018 21:34:20.426 queries: info: client 74.99.171.161#80 (eftps.gov): query: eftps.gov IN ANY +E (192.168.0.200)
27-Sep-2018 21:34:20.438 queries: info: client 217.107.34.85#51622 (aids.gov): query: aids.gov IN ANY +E (192.168.0.200)
27-Sep-2018 21:34:20.570 queries: info: client 70.29.66.36#47689 (eftps.gov): query: eftps.gov IN ANY +E (192.168.0.200)
27-Sep-2018 21:34:20.794 queries: info: client 109.148.129.56#37777 (eftps.gov): query: eftps.gov IN ANY +E (192.168.0.200)
27-Sep-2018 21:34:20.918 queries: info: client 74.99.171.161#80 (isc.org): query: isc.org IN ANY +E (192.168.0.200)
27-Sep-2018 21:34:20.941 queries: info: client 217.107.34.85#16138 (aids.gov): query: aids.gov IN ANY +E (192.168.0.200)
27-Sep-2018 21:34:20.961 queries: info: client 74.99.171.161#80 (isc.org): query: isc.org IN ANY +E (192.168.0.200)
27-Sep-2018 21:34:21.145 queries: info: client 74.99.171.161#80 (aids.gov): query: aids.gov IN ANY +E (192.168.0.200)
27-Sep-2018 21:34:21.156 queries: info: client 92.11.206.190#80 (isc.org): query: isc.org IN ANY +E (192.168.0.200)
27-Sep-2018 21:34:21.381 queries: info: client 68.84.209.198#80 (jk1l.ru): query: jk1l.ru IN ANY +E (192.168.0.200)
27-Sep-2018 21:34:21.382 queries: info: client 68.84.209.198#80 (jk1l.ru): query: jk1l.ru IN ANY +E (192.168.0.200)
27-Sep-2018 21:34:21.417 queries: info: client 74.99.171.161#80 (isc.org): query: isc.org IN ANY +E (192.168.0.200)
27-Sep-2018 21:34:21.421 queries: info: client 68.84.209.198#80 (jk1l.ru): query: jk1l.ru IN ANY +E (192.168.0.200)
27-Sep-2018 21:34:21.513 queries: info: client 68.84.209.198#80 (jk1l.ru): query: jk1l.ru IN ANY +E (192.168.0.200)
```

should i be worried?

Comment: Yes. When your server is actually responding to those requests your server is possibly used for a dns reflection & amplification attack https://deepthought.isc.org/article/AA-00897/0/What-is-a-DNS-Amplification-Attack.html

Comment: And what to do next? Take a look at e.g. [Use fail2ban Bind9 be used to prevent DNS amplification attacks](https://www.logcg.com/en/archives/1681.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was in fact used for dns reflection & amplification attack as said by @HBruijn 
The solution was to [restrict recursion to internal clients by setting acls](http://www.networkinghowtos.com/howto/prevent-dns-amplification-attacks-with-bind/).

Comment: Please include the relevant information on how to solve the problem in the answer itself, see https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer for some general guidance ("Provide context for links" in particular in this case)

Answer (score 5):

First of all, regarding the log entries it may be of interest to just point out [what the values in the query log mean](https://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.11/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#the_category_phrase):

> The query log entry first reports a client object identifier in
>   @0x format. Next, it reports the client's IP
>   address and port number, and the query name, class and type. Next, it
>   reports whether the Recursion Desired flag was set (+ if set, - if not
>   set), if the query was signed (S), EDNS was in used along with the
>   EDNS version number (E(#)), if TCP was used (T), if DO (DNSSEC Ok) was
>   set (D), if CD (Checking Disabled) was set (C), if a valid DNS Server
>   COOKIE was received (V), or if a DNS COOKIE option without a valid
>   Server COOKIE was present (K). After this the destination address the
>   query was sent to is reported.

Looking at one of your entries (essentially all the same):

```
27-Sep-2018 21:34:19.796 queries: info: client 217.107.34.85#22807 (isc.org): query: isc.org IN ANY +E (192.168.0.200)
```

We see `+` (recursion desired) and `E` (EDNS) and that the qtype is `ANY`.
Also relevant is the absence of `T` (TCP).

This is a combination that, when picking a domain name where they know that there is a large amount of records, essentially optimizes for getting an as large response as possible sent back over UDP. 
(Recursion to be able to use any domain name of choice, EDNS to allow for >512 byte answers over UDP (easily spoofable).)

This is more or less ideal for [reflection amplification DDoS attacks](https://deepthought.isc.org/article/AA-00897/0/What-is-a-DNS-Amplification-Attack.html), where the attacker spams a large number of tiny queries with their victim's IP address as the source address, having your server send the resulting large responses to the address of the victim.

The obvious things to look into to solve this are:

- You probably have no good reason to allow recursion to the general public, if at all. You will want to disable this! See [`allow-recursion`](https://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.10/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#access_control) for limiting recursion access to only your intended clients or the [`recursion`](https://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.10/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#boolean_options) to disable recursion altogether.
- BIND also has [Response-Rate Limiting](https://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.10/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#rrl) built in, which allows you to rate-limit identical queries from your allowed clients (see previous bullet point). Either forcing clients that exceed your configured threshold value to switch to TCP (not trivially spoofable) in order to actually get the actual answers or to start dropping responses altogether.

In the bigger picture, ISPs should be filtering the source IP of their customers (see [BCP38](https://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp38)) to limit the possibility of anyone just claiming to be any IP address (as is done in this type of spoofing).